# can't debug my application because of the "windows has detected that this application did not run correctly" dialog

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-7

I have a windows application running using VS2010, and when it crashes because of exception I get a "windows has detected that this application did not run correctly" dialog instead of the debugger being stopped!!! And I don't know how to turn it off! I've read in "help" that it is somewhere in the group policy settings in my control panel (*Adjustments to program compatibility features can be made by using Group Policy.*), but I haven't found this configuration in the group policy settings. So how do I turn this useless feature off?

Comment: Are you debugging 32-bit code on a 64-bit version of Windows?